# Mean of Numpy Array Error

Tags: python, numpy

I am importing data from a tsv file as a list which I then convert into a numpy array.  I have done this many times before but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.  Here is my code

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def import_data(file_path):
    data=[]
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        next(file)
        reader=csv.reader(file,delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            data.append(map(float,row[1:60]))
    return data



def main():

    data=import_data("my_file.tsv")
    new_data=np.array(data)
    print np.mean(new_data)
```

The error that occurs in the line that calculates the mean an it says

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Can anyone explain this to me?  Didn't I convert the list to a numpy array in the previous line?

Comment: Please post the entire error message, not just the last line.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the tsv file had empty cells in it.

Comment: Are you able to isolate a line of your tsv file that causes the error and post it in your question?

Comment: No, but my code works on other examples, so I am almost sure that it is a problem with the empty cells in the tsv file.